# How can I fix a Function ereg is deprecated in

Tags: function, deprecated

I have a script, albeit old, that is having the following error

```
PHP Deprecated:  Function ereg() is deprecated in /home/mysite/public_html/lang/index.php on line 12
```

line 12 has this code

```
ereg('([a-z]{1,2})(-([a-z0-9]+))?(;q=([0-9\.]+))?',$lang,$found);
```

Can I replace this with something else to stop this error?

Cheers